# Sleep() Function not timing properly in C

Tags: c, sleep, unistd.h

I've been coding some simple things such as printing statements but I wanted to have my processor sleeping to not have too many printing statements at the same time.
I've used the library **unistd.h** and used the function **sleep()**.
The problem I have encountered is that when I ask the sleep function to sleep less then one second like 0.9 is printing the same quantity of statements as if I wasn't using the function **sleep()** at all.
It's working fine if I make it sleep more than one second but I don't want one second of sleep, I want less.

Tank you kindly for reading and/or helping.

Comment: You'd have wanted to read the `sleep()` manpage before asking. This would have told you that some of your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Please read the manual page - it oly sleeps for an integral number of seconds. Usleep perhaps

Comment: What makes you think it can take a float? Have you read the documentation of sleep?

Comment: So when you `sleep` does your program do nothing? There are creative ways to use your time slice, such as taking an average, or only printing when the value changes. On the other hand if you have "too many printing statements" you could redirect the program output to a text file and read it at your leisure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP did not read the man page for sleep before asking his question

Answer (score 5):

If you read [the `sleep` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) you will see that it takes the time in seconds as an *integer*.

If you use a floating-point value when an integer value is expected, the compiler will truncate it. For example the floating-point value `0.9` will be truncated to the integer `0`.

So what you are doing is effectively `sleep(0)`.

Also on [the `sleep` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) (at least for the Linux manual page) you will see a link to [the `nanosleep` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html).